# Can I use insert values to table with Sql query in Hibernate which is not entity of hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, insert, entity

I am developing in a project. I use hibernate. I want to insert values to a table in db with sql query of hibernate. But errors occur. Maybe, I can not use insert values to table with Sql query in Hibernate which is not entity of hibernate.

This is right?

query:

```
getSession().createSQLQuery("insert into product_cdc (id,name) values (1,'ali')").executeUpdate();
```

query is above and very small. But product_cdc is not entity of hibernate

```
error: Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PRODUCT_CDC
```

Comment: Please show the query that is not working.

Comment: Maybe, product_cdc has not created. This code in unit test. It table is created in hsql. Error is happened in creation table.

Comment: either the table doesn't exist or the user doesn't have privilege. Although why in the world would you try to insert using a insert SQL query with hibernate ? Just create & save the bean to the hibernate session